# How to keep booklet format and add two pages of normal format at the end?

Tags: microsoft-word

I made an employee handbook (booklet format) now I want to add two normal page documents (sign-off docs.) to the end of the booklet so that everything is in one file ready to print. I have tried copy and paste and the sign-off pages convert to half sheets size (booklet) or if I use keep formatting the entire booklet changes to normal page size. I also tried to use the page set-up and change to 'from this point forward' and again the booklet format is removed. Any ideas? is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding a new section at the end of the booklet? Sometimes, it's easier to insert the new section at the *beginning* of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear how you envision this printing and being distributed, or whether the full-size sheets only need to be viewed, or separated and returned.

#### If the full-size pages only need to be viewed at full-size

This would require some manual intervention, and presenting it as the top and bottom halves of the page viewed as adjacent top and bottom halves but actually on different sheets.

Booklet format is a collection of half-size pages, four portrait pages to a landscape sheet.  It gets folded in half and stacked, so you're looking at two pages side-by side, potentially stapled down the middle.  Most of the adjacent pages are actually parts of different sheets of paper, sequenced to be in the proper order once the sheets are folded and stacked.  The only places you see both halves of the same sheet are the outside cover and the center two pages.

Some booklet printing utilities shrink and rotate full size portrait pages to fit the half-page landscape print format.  Others let you prepare the actual half-size portrait page images.  In either case, the utility has you prepare the pages in reading order, then rearranges the pages as needed for printing the booklet sheets.

The only way you could physically incorporate the full-size pages would be to split the full-size pages vertically into top and bottom halves.  Each half would be oriented landscape and positioned as sequential pages at the end, before the back cover.  So, for example, if you start at the back and open the back cover, and turn the booklet sideways, you would see the top and bottom halves of the page, looking like the complete page, but actually each half being part of a different sheet.

Single-fold standard booklets are multiples of four pages (four half-page images per sheet).  The cover (front and back), outsides and insides, are one sheet.  If your document without the cover is not a multiple of four pages, blank placeholder pages are inserted at the end to make it a multiple of complete sheets.

For the full size sheets to have their top and bottom halves adjacent at the end of the booklet, they need a specific page sequence relative to the cover.  The bottom half of the last page could be the inside of the back cover.  Or if the inside of the back cover is reserved for specific content or must be blank, you would insert a blank last page before the inside of the back cover.  Then any remaining blank pages to make the booklet body a multiple of four pages would need to be inserted before the full-size sheets.

If the booklet printer shrinks pages to fit, you would start with a double-size version of the two halves of the full-size pages.  If it lets you prepare the actual size pages, you would start a landscape section at the end, include the sequential top and bottom halves, then use another section to switch back to portrait.

If you can't easily produce double-size pages, or your booklet utility can't work with them (or with a mix of page sizes), you could generate the booklet to a PDF with blank placeholders for the four top and bottom halves, produce those separately, then merge them into the PDF, replacing the blank placeholder pages.

#### If the full-size pages need to be detachable

If the full-size pages are forms that need to be returned, they can't be part of the actual booklet.

**If you are distributing a print file**

You could produce the booklet and print it to a PDF driver, which would output the booklet pages ready for printing.  Output the full-sized pages to another PDF.  Then merge the two PDF files so the full-size pages are either first or last.  The recipient would be instructed to print the whole PDF, remove the full size pages, then fold and stack the booklet pages.

**If you are doing the printing and distributing hard copies**

there are a couple of other options.

- Print the booklet and full-sized pages separately, fold the full-sized pages in half, and insert them into the finished booklet before the back cover (so they are loose pages).
- Design the full-page sheets so the whole page doesn't need to be returned, only a portion (less than half).  Pre-perforated paper is available with a cleanly detachable portion, which would be used for the part that must be returned.  Prepare everything as described under "View-only", except arrange extra blank pages so that the page after the detachable portion is blank (or the outside of the back cover), and there is an additional blank page between the two full-size pages (so the top of the second full-size page is printed on something permanent).  This approach requires a lot of planning and preparation to ensure that the supply paper is correctly sequenced and oriented to put the detachable areas in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a section break (next page) just before the pages in question. You can change the page size to anything you want.

Comment: On a regular document, yes.  How would this work with a booklet printer?  Those pages share portions of sheets of paper with other pages.